# Using the timer to check a condition inside a if

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, nstimer

I have to develop an application where it does following things,

1. Switch is used to initiate the accelerometer
2. Then accelerometer data is inserted to an array of size 5
3. Then use those accelerometer data to calculate a output value using a equation
4. Every times a new reading comes, i delete the last element of the array and add it to the array( array remains dynamic through out the loop
5. Then i want to compare whether the output calculated is greater than a specified value and update a global counter?

I implemented this by using a if condition

```
if(output>10){
[[shared sharedInstance].counter++;
}
```

(all above are implemented and they work perfectly)

BUT the problem is.....................

I want to check this if condition, used to update to be active for 5ms and deactivate for 10ms but it's also important to "NOT" to stop the accelerometer data process and calculating output.

So i thought that i can implement two global variables and set their values as shown below
1. var_x - set it's value for 1 for 5ms after that set it to 10ms and this process should repeat continuously and it should start after the user activate accelerometer,

So by using this inside my if condition i can make sure it check the condition after 10ms and keep on checking for 5ms
like this.........

```
if(output>10 && [[shared sharedInstance].var_x >1){
[[shared sharedInstance].counter++;
}
```

can anyone help me to code this timing function inside the global variable to set the variable value to 1 and 0 ? (

Comment: typo? you open two square brackets and close only one...

Comment: @Saphrosit What do you mean by that?

Comment: You wrote `[[shared sharedInstance]`. You open two brackets and you close one. Is this just an error in copying the code here?

Comment: @Saphrosit - It's a mistake by me! Sorry! Any idea to get my work done? I tried Hejazi ans, his logic works But not that accurate at smaller time intervals! Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)turnCheckOn {
    doCheck = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(turnCheckOff) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.005];
}

- (void)turnCheckOff {
    doCheck = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(turnCheckOn) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.010];
}
```

Then call `turnCheckOn` once.

Comment: Dear sir, thank you for ur valuable answer! Can you tell me how to call turnCheckOn inside the if loop! I m bit new to coding! If you dnt mind, can you please help me get it done? Thank you~

Comment: You can call it in the `init` method for example.

Comment: But how to integrate it with the other condition(output>10) with it?

Comment: Dude got it working! But unfortunately this method does not detect reading in ms! Delay is too high! Any other way, i can get this done?

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed the time delay. Try it now.